# Lua function only works on first click

Tags: lua

I'm new to Lua, and I'm trying to do a simple program to change the location of an object randomly when it's clicked.  The problem is, this program only works once, that is to say, upon loading the program and tapping the circle, it moves, but will not move again on subsequent taps.  Any ideas?

```
local _W = display.contentWidth
local _H = display.contentHeight
math.randomseed(os.time())
math.random()
myCircle = display.newCircle(_W * 0.25, _H * 0.25, 50)
local function moveCircle(event)
    h_random = math.random()
    w_random = math.random()
    display.remove(myCircle)
    myCircle = display.newCircle(_W * w_random, _H * h_random, 50)
    return true
end
myCircle:addEventListener("tap",moveCircle)
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You should make `h_random` and `w_random` local variables if they aren't being used anywhere else. Also, what framework are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any idea of what library you are using :) But try adding

```
myCircle:addEventListener("tap",moveCircle)
```

before `return true` in the `moveCircle` function.

From what I can understand from a quick inspection of the code snippet, the proposed change will bind the  tap event to the newly created circle.